# How do I a list that stops when a blank space is entered and removes duplicates in Python

Tags: python

I have to create a function that creates a list with items given by the user and it stops creating a list when a space is given.  It must then remove duplicates from this list. I cannot use the built in function `set()`. This is what I have but when a space is given a `TypeError` occurs.

```
def assignment():
  x = input('Type anything')
  random_list = []
  while x != '':
    x = input("Type anything")
    random_list.append(x)
    print(random_list)
  x=x+1
  for i in random_list:
    if i not in random_list:
      random_list.append(i) 
assignment()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<stdin>", line 8, in assignment
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: What's `x=x+1`? You're adding an integer `1` to a string `x`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Would deleting x=x+1 make more sense?

Comment: @dude  That typeerror is because of that same cause

Comment: @dude, why did you put it in there in the first place, provided that you aren't using `x` after that line? Only that suggests this line is useless, but for you it also causes the exception. So yeah, you should delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the statememt `x=x+1` is useless and buggy. :/

I rearranged your code to this one:

```
def assignment():
    random_list = []
    final_list = []
    while True:
        x = input("Type anything")
        if x!='':
            random_list.append(x)
        else:
            break
    for i in random_list:
        if i not in final_list:
            final_list.append(i) 
    return final_list
assignment()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `input` function returns a string, so your variable `x` becomes a string when it's assigned with the returning value of `input`, and trying to add an integer to a string with `x+1` produces the `TypeError` exception.

For your purpose you don't actually need to increment `x` at all. Remove `x=x+1`, and avoid appending `x` to `random_list` with a `break` when `x` is empty. Use another condition with the `in` operator to avoid adding duplicates:

```
while True:
    x = input("Type anything")
    if x == '':
        break
    if x not in random_list:
        random_list.append(x)
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you. Can a function to remove duplicates be added on to this?

Answer (score 0):

How about (tested under python 2.7 and 3.6.6)

```
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    input_func = input
else:
    input_func = raw_input

user_data = []
while True:
    item = input_func('Type input please:')
    if item == ' ':
        break
    if item not in user_data:
        user_data.add(item)
print(user_data)
```